# Pass a reference to a file rather than a file itself with Python

Tags: python, celery

I can't seem to identify how to create a file in Python and then pass around a reference to the file in order to convert it to different image resolutions.

I'm using Celery to generate these various image resolutions asynchronously and passing the entire image consumes too much memory and eventually causes out of memory errors.

Any suggestions on how I should accomplish this? Here's some code for illustration:

```
file_object = open('/tmp/image.jpg', 'w+')

with api.fetch_remote_file() as f:

    file_object.write(f.read())
    file_object.seek(0)

    # Pass a file object through a chain of functions to generate new images
    chain = generate_images.s(file_object, "high") | generate_images.s(file_object, "medium") | delete_temp(file_object)
    chain()



# A Celery task to process images asynchronously from a queue
@app.task
def generate_images(file_object, quality):

    #Convert the image to a lower resolution and store it
    image = convert(file_object.read())

    return file_object, image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the absolute path of the file to the celery workers. And let worker open the file and then read the content.

Comment: Oh man. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I was so deep into what I was doing that the simplest of solutions evaded me. Thank you so kindly!